# Apache - How to check if TestString is a valid URL in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to check if test string is a valid remote url and I found the `-U` condition

About the `-U` condition in [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> '-U' (is existing URL, via subrequest) Checks whether or not
>   TestString is a valid URL, accessible via all the server's
>   currently-configured access controls for that path. This uses an
>   internal subrequest to do the check, so use it with care - it can
>   impact your server's performance!

Both following conditions redirect to hello.php

```
RewriteCond ^http://google.com$ -U
RewriteRule ^.* hello.php?test=true [L]

RewriteCond ^google$ -U
RewriteRule ^.* hello.php?test=true [L]
```

There is few information about what `-U` is really doing.

Q1- Is it checking a local URL or a remote one?

Q2- Is it requesting the URL or parsing it?

**EDITED**

Redirecting to hello.php

```
RewriteCond ^localhost$ -U
RewriteRule ^.* hello.php [L]

RewriteCond ^http//localhost$ -U
RewriteRule ^.* hello.php [L]

RewriteCond ^?localhost$ -U
RewriteRule ^.* hello.php [L]
```

Not redirecting to hello.php

```
RewriteCond ^http://localhost$ -U
RewriteRule ^.* hello.php [L]

RewriteCond ^:localhost$ -U
RewriteRule ^.* hello.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make `-U` return true:

```
RewriteCond ^localhost$ -U
RewriteRule ^foo index.php?test=true [L,QSA]
```

To make `-U` return false:

```
RewriteCond ^http://localhost$ -U
RewriteRule ^foo index.php?test=true [L,QSA]
```

It appears to me it checks valid URL without protocol in front i.e. `http://` or `https://` part.

**In my testing I didn't find it issuing any `HEAD` request to web server.**

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I don't get it... any of both redirect to index.php. Maybe because of `foo`... But you have a point, -U is reacting according to the protocole. I have edited the question. Can you have a look.

Comment: -U is reacting according to the colon character... even more confusing :)

Comment: Interestingly I've found in addition to colon it also returns false when it finds `%` or `*` in URL while checking `-U` condition.

Comment: Yes definitely it is not issuing any `HEAD` request.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it does all of the above, by making a HTTP HEAD request to the specified resource.

The status code from the response of the HEAD request is used to determine the accessibility and state of the resource.

Comment: Thanks William. Based on your answer why both above conditions return TRUE. Could you please provide an example of a proper way to implement it?

Comment: I think you are confusing true with false. I recon both those conditions will return FALSE on you Apache server.

Comment: I have edited the question. Both following conditions redirect to hello.php which means both RewriteCond are valid except `^google$` is neither a valid/existing url nor a valid/existing path